# Jenkins agent node setup

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have setup a Jenkins controller and I want to add an agent node in the same network. Do I need to install Jenkins on the agent machine? Or can I use any arbitrary machine without having to install Jenkins on it first?

Comment: Did you try this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines?

Comment: No, I didn't! and it seems to provide the information I need, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up new Jenkins slave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477290/how-to-set-up-new-jenkins-slave)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't need to install Jenkins in any slave machine at all.

You will need, if it is a [Linux slave, just SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Havemasterlaunchslaveagentviassh) access enabled.
If it is a Windows machine, then Java and [connect with the jar](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Launchslaveagentheadlessly) provided by Jenkins or [through Java Web client](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallSlaveasaWindowsservice%28require.NET2.0framework%29).

On Linux and for Java, Jenkins will download anything he needs.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install jenkins on slave machine , you just ned to download slave.jar in your slave machine and you can connnect slave using TCP port for JNLP agents .

https://www.automation99.com/2017/09/how-to-setup-jenkins-slave-machine.html